# Illustrator layer selection style

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Illustrator doesn't care about selected layer. I can directly pick objects from any layers. I want Illustrator pick object within only selected layer.

I learned Photoshop interacts only selected layer.

Can Illustrator behave like Photoshop's layer interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Use **Isolation Mode**

Double-click on the object or group you wish to isolate with the Selection Tool, to enter Isolation Mode.

Double-click anywhere outside of the object/group to leave Isolation Mode

You can also enter Isolation Mode the hard way, through the Layers Panel. Select the layer or group to isolate and then use the Layers Panel menu (on the right in the image below) to navigate to Enter Isolation Mode

[image]

[More info on Isolation Mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-isolation-mode-isolate-artwork.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few workarounds for this:

1. Lock the layers with objects you don't want to be selectable.
2. Lock just the items you want to remain static:

> Lock a selection = Ctrl + 2 (Command + 2)
>
> Lock all deselected artwork = Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 2 (Command + Option + Shift + 2)
>
> Unlock a selection = Alt + Ctrl + 2 (Option + Command + 2)

3. Hide just the items you want to remain static:

> Hide a selection = Ctrl + 3 (Command + 3)
>
> Show all selections = Alt + Ctrl +  (Option + Command + 3)